# Can I block certain private Chatter Group members from seeing specific posts based on record ownership?

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed, chatter-groups

We have a couple of private chatter groups with several members in each one but we only want the owner of an updated object record ( using feed tracking)  to receive/see posts in those chatter groups while the others can't. Is there a way to do this?

Example: Only Account Owners get to see a feed  post when their account record's registration status field or Health Status fields has been updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Feed Tracking is enabled, only users who have access to the field that is being updated will see the feed post that is created.

You can use Field Level Security (FLS) to control who can and cannot see a particular field.

With Feed Tracking enabled on a field and the field changes a Feed Post is generated in the feed for that object (Account for example). It doesn't get posted to a private group.

Any post in a private group can be seen by all members of that group.

Comment: Thanks Paul: Then it looks like I would have to dynamically (using code) create private sub chatter groups for each of the 19 field reps so that they can receive their chatter posts in secret and then. 2) These 19 field reps can also be members of the larger Private Group in order to do basic Chatter posts, memos, file attachments they can share. Thus each field rep would belong to 2 groups: One for him/herself and the Large Private group consisting of all 19 members. The feed will be directed to the correct sub private group based on userId match. That's the only way I can see this happening.